# Facebook API Unsupported get request facebook-graph-api

Tags: php, web, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to configure the application for a long time
I am using Graph API Explorer
I just want to find out information about another user, but I get this error
the user is active, I do not understand how exactly I need to configure the application, where and what permissions to issue
I really ask for help

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '**********' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_subcode": 33,
    "fbtrace_id": "AX-5LamyFX-eTYk9c0WZdHj"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can not just get information about other users, just because you want to … this other user would have to log in to your application, and grant it the necessary permissions first.

Comment: @04FS , How do I get public information about users? name, number of posts, information about each user's post: likes, reposts?

Comment: You simply _don’t_. Publicly accessible via the UI, and accessible via API, are two different things. You need permission from the user in question, to get any of that info via API.